Validation rule that excludes a picklist doesn't work
I have a validation rule that prevents the case from closing if it does not have an associated account, however, I need to ignore this rule if the picklist value is "E-mails que não são casos".
I tried this, but it's not working:
(NOT CONTAINS($User.LastName , 'Sistema')) && (
AND(
RecordType.DeveloperName == 'EmailAtendimento',             
NOT(ISPICKVAL(QualificacaoMeoo__c, "E-mails Que Não São Casos")),
ISCHANGED( Status ),
OR(
ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Fechado"),
ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Fechado Parcialmente"),
ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Réplica sem ação"),
ISPICKVAL( Status ,"Réplica tratada")
),
ISBLANK(AccountId)
))

I've added this NOT(ISPICKVAL(Qualificacao__c, "E-mails Que Não São Casos")), after. Before was respecting all the conditions.
Someone help? =)

Olá e bem-vindo ao SFSE! Observe que somos um site que fala inglês e todas as perguntas e respostas devem estar em inglês. Edite sua postagem e use o melhor inglês possível. Nós o ajudaremos a corrigir quaisquer erros gramaticais que você possa cometer. Peço desculpas por quaisquer erros de tradução, pois estou usando o Google Tradutor.

I think the first && is messing everything up. You shouldn't need this. Try this?
If it doesn't work, I would remove the OR block and work backwards until it works and then start reading the values.
AND(
 (NOT CONTAINS($User.LastName , 'Sistema')),
 RecordType.DeveloperName == 'EmailAtendimento',        
 ISBLANK(AccountId),        
 NOT(ISPICKVAL(QualificacaoMeoo__c, "E-mails Que Não São Casos")),
 ISCHANGED(Status),
 OR(
  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Fechado"),
  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Fechado Parcialmente"),
  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Réplica sem ação"),
  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Réplica tratada")
 )
)


Questions and answers must be in English. Please [edit] your answer to be written in English. Thanks!
